# SequelizeConnectionRefusedError errno:-111 ECONNREFUSED

Tags: node.js, express

I got following exception on node.js express and how can I troubleshoot it?

{"name":"SequelizeConnectionRefusedError","parent":{"errno":-111,"code":"ECONNREFUSED","syscall":"connect","address":"127.0.0.1","port":6432},"original":{"errno":-111,"code":"ECONNREFUSED","syscall":"connect","address":"127.0.0.1","port":6432}}

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this exception because your app cannot connect to the database server in localhost and port 6432.
Please make sure your database server is  up and running on port 6432 in your localhost

Comment: Thanks. I have debugging the program and I found something wrong in the SQL statement. 
i.e.
"SELECT \"cpuid\", \"last_update\", \"hostid\", \"Vendor\", \"model\", \"cpu\", \"memory\", \"disk_7135_110\", \"disk_7135_210\", \"disk_9334\", \"ssa_disk\", \"internal_disk\", \"peripheral\", \"os\", \"db\", \"software\", \"ipadd\", \"alt_ipadd\", \"location\", \"ts\", \"usage\", \"remarks\" FROM \"configuration\" AS \"Configuration\";"

How can I make "FROM \"configuration\" AS \"Configuration\";" into
"FROM configuration;"